# Double integrals of modulo x + modulo y

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Is the following statement:

$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}{\int_{y_1}^{y_2}{g(x)+h(y)dxdy}} = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}{g(x)dx} + \int_{y_1}^{y_2}{h(y)dy} $

False in the general case ? Does it hold if $g(x) =|x|$ and $h(y) = |y| $ ?

Thanks in advance

EDIT : answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general that's false, but a similar result is true:

$ \begin{align} 
\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\int_{y_1}^{y_2}g(x)+h(y)\ dxdy &= \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\int_{y_1}^{y_2}g(x)\ dxdy + \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\int_{y_1}^{y_2} h(y)\ dxdy \\
&= (y_2-y_1)\int_{x_1}^{x_2}g(x)\ dx + (x_2-x_1)\int_{y_1}^{y_2}h(y)\ dy
\end{align} $

Comment: @JavierBadia Consider giving a proof for both equalities.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId: Both follow from the linearity properties of the integral. I didn't include a proof because I thought they were pretty straightforward.